# Stacktrace is no longer symbolicated

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, logging, symbolicatecrash

I do my own error handling by catching any exceptions and logging them manually. I use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&myExceptionHandler);` and log the stack trace using `[NSException callStackSymbols]`. Up until recently my logs contained the symbolicated stack trace. Now they don't and there weren't any code changes related to the logging. This is occurring on all devices and versions of iOS. I am able to manually symbolicate my logs but it is quite cumbersome. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Previously my logs looked like:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x352925b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   MYAPP                           0x0006573a -[MyViewController(Images) didReceiveImage:context:etag:expires:] + 42
2   MYAPP                           0x0004fb26 -[MyImageTask didReceiveImage:] + 98
3   Foundation                      0x361ac8e8 __NSThreadPerformPerform
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3b37d680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3b37cee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3b37bcb2 __CFRunLoopRun
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3b2eeeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3b2eed44 CFRunLoopRunInMode
9   GraphicsServices                0x396bc2e6 GSEventRunModal
10  UIKit                           0x3452e2f4 UIApplicationMain
11  MYAPP                           0x0004934a main + 70
12  MYAPP                           0x000492fc start + 36
```

After my last release they look like:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x352925b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   MYAPP                           0x0006573a - MYAPP + 42
2   MYAPP                           0x0004fb26 - MYAPP + 98
3   Foundation                      0x361ac8e8 __NSThreadPerformPerform
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3b37d680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3b37cee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3b37bcb2 __CFRunLoopRun
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3b2eeeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3b2eed44 CFRunLoopRunInMode
9   GraphicsServices                0x396bc2e6 GSEventRunModal
10  UIKit                           0x3452e2f4 UIApplicationMain
11  MYAPP                           0x0004934a main + 70
12  MYAPP                           0x000492fc start + 36
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Apple now performs a kind of repackaging and eventually stripping debug info.